# How can I add / renew CA cert's which pantheon-files is using?

Tags: release-loki, pantheon-files, security

I wanted to mount my webdav share which is using certificate backed by CA "Let's Encrypt". Unfortunately pantheon-files declare that CA is not trusted (not found). 
This CA is perfectly workable and fine in firefox. Do they use different cert store, pantheon-files and firefox?

Comment: I was not trying to ask for fixing a bug, I was asking for help how to update CA store which is used by pantheon-files.

Comment: It seems that one not get here any help only he is always showed s door to leave :-( pity.

Comment: For those who prefer answers in place of bugging here is the solution: go to lets encrypt web site (or any other missing CA cert site) and follow this: http://superuser.com/questions/437330/how-do-you-add-a-certificate-authority-ca-to-ubuntu don't forget to rename cert with extension .crt

Comment: apologies that your question was misunderstood. lemonslice submitted a few edits to try to clarify. If you were able to find the answer, can you please post it below as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the CA which is missing. In my case:go to lets encrypt web site (or any other missing CA cert site). Copy the CA in PEM format (the format that has ----BEGIN CERTIFICATE---- in it) into `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` and **name it with a .crt file extension**.

Then run `sudo update-ca-certificates`

You can verify if this worked by looking for the certificate that you just added in `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt/`